# Name of a second order statistical quantity similar to generalized variance

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix, determinant

I am looking for the name of a statistical quantity similar to generalized variance in a 2 dimensional space.  Specifically, I define generalized variance as
$\epsilon_{a,b}^2 = \left|\begin{matrix}\sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{a,b}\\\sigma_{a,b} & \sigma_b^2\end{matrix}\right|$ where $|\cdot|$ is short for determinant.  What I am looking for is the name of the quantity  $\epsilon_{a,b,c,d} = \left|\begin{matrix}\sigma_{a,b} & \sigma_{b,d}\\\sigma_{a,c} & \sigma_{c,d}\end{matrix}\right|$.  Notice $\epsilon_{a,b}^2 = \epsilon_{a,a,b,b}$, and for this reason I want to call $\epsilon_{a,b,c,d}$ the generalized covariance, but as that term means invariance of physical laws under coordinate transformations in the physics literature, I am hesitant to use it without literature support.  Has anyone seen $\epsilon_{a,b,c,d}$ anywhere, and if so, could you point me to the correct terminology or some literature?

Comment: By "$\sigma_{a,b}$" *etc* do you mean covariances between random variables?  There are many things your determinant could be called, so the choice really ought to depend on (a) how you intend to interpret or use it and (b) your intended audience.

Comment: Yes.  By $\sigma_{a,b}$, I do mean the covariances between random variables.  I am offering little interpretation of $\sigma_{a,b,c,d}$, but it simplifies derivations for time-dependent statistics of $\frac{1}{mc} \epsilon_{x(t),p_x(t)}$, which is called the emittance in the field I am in (accelerator physics --- also the intended audience).  In this community, emittance is synonymous to area in $x$-$p_x$ space, but I am planning on elucidating emittance squared, which I want to borrow the term generalized variance for (that term is currently not in my field).

Comment: Variances of phase space volumes will be just that: there won't be any standard statistical term for them.